# PHP - If div class appears on page - Hide separate element

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an `<a></a>` tag on my page surrounding some content which I'm pulling through from Advanced Custom Fields.

This is all good but I would like the a link to be conditional.

I'd like the comment to be: if .client-quote class is on the page, hide the a tag.

Here's the whole loop code:

```
<!-- Main Loop =========================================== -->


<div class="container blog-card-container">
    <div class="card-columns">


        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>






                <?php if( get_field('quote') ): ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                <?php endif; ?>



                    <div class="card">





                        <!-- Image if loop =========================================== -->

                        <?php if ( in_category('14') ) : ?>


                            <div class="client-header-logo-card" style="background-color: <?php the_field('client_brand_colour'); ?>;">
                                <?php 

                                $image = get_field('client_logo');

                                if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>              

                        <?php else: ?>

                            <div class="blog-thumb-container">
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
                            </div>                          

                        <?php endif ?>




                        <!-- Meta Data if loop =========================================== -->

                        <div class="blog-clients-card-block">

                            <?php if ( in_category('14') ) : ?>

                                <div class="client-text-block">

                                    <p class="blog-cat-label"><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>

                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                                    <?php if( get_field('quote') ): ?><p class="client-quote"><span style="color:<?php the_field('client_brand_colour'); ?>; font-weight:bold;">&ldquo; </span><?php the_field('quote'); ?><span style="color:<?php the_field('client_brand_colour'); ?>;font-weight:bold;"> &rdquo;</span></p><?php endif; ?>


                                    <?php if( get_field('quote_name') ): ?><p class="client-name" style="color:<?php the_field('client_brand_colour'); ?>;"><?php the_field('quote_name'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if( get_field('quote_position') ): ?><p class="client-position" style="color:<?php the_field('client_brand_colour'); ?>;"><?php the_field('quote_position'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>


                                    <?php if( get_field('button_text') ): ?>
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-client-archive" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-color:<?php the_field('client_brand_colour'); ?>;" role="button"><?php the_field('button_text'); ?></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if( get_field('video_url') ): ?>
                                        <div class="embed-container">
                                            <?php the_field('video_url'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>       

                                </div>

                            <?php else: ?>

                                <p class="blog-cat-label"><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
                                <h2 class="blog-card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
                                <p><strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong> | <?php the_date(); ?> </p>

                            <?php endif ?>


                        </div>




            <?php if( get_field('quote') ): ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>




        </div>



        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>



    </div>

</div>
```

Ive tried adding if tags around the a link like so:

```
<?php if( get_field('quote') ): ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
<?php endif; ?>

CODE AND CONTENT HERE

<?php if( get_field('quote') ): ?>
   </a> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I assume because it might run before the loop inside it? So its confusing me a little... Perhaps I need a function to run after the page has loaded or something similar? Im not entirely sure.

Any help massively appreciated as it's driving me mad!

Comment: You can not nest links into each other, so as long as you are outputting a link for the `button_text` field inside, you can not wrap another link around the whole thing.

Comment: What does `get_field('quote')` return when it doesn't have a value in it? Can you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: Can you show us the loop part?
You probably could store the value of get_field('quote') : 
<?php 
$currentQuote = get_field('quote');
$hasQuote = $hasQuote ? $hasQuote : $currentQuote;
?>
Then use $currentQuote inside your loop, and $hasQuote outside the loop
Using javascript on this case is a bad idea, overloading your frontend with no reason.

Comment: @BenoitNgô - Thanks, I'll look at this - Ive added the whole loop, its a big large and contains a big if statement to display one type or the other type of content...

Comment: I'm not sure @TahaPaksu - When it doesnt have a value in it it just doesn't simply the div.

Comment: I think I can @CBroe - with HTML5 You can wrap a whole dix with an class...

Comment: No, you can not nest links into each other in HTML, and that hasn’t changed with HTML5 either. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element: _“Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.”_

Comment: Ok Apologies @CBroe - I was under he impression I could - But lets say I were to move the a link to just be on the image instead of the whole div - It still wont solve the problem as Ill still be looking for the bit of code to hide the link though

Comment: Have you verified what value `get_field('quote')` actually returns in those cases? Is it really a false-y one? Do a var_dump of the value to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a php Check to see if its there, and put your results in your variable($yourTag).  After that echo it wherever you want in your body.

```
<?php 
if(get_field('quote') == ''){
$yourTag = "<a href=\"".get_the_permalink()."\">" ;
} else {
$yourTag = "";
}
?>
```

Then place it wherever you want in your HTML like this

```
<div> <?php echo $yourTag; ?> </div>
```

Comment: Ive tried to add this Jonny, currently outside the loop but it just crashes the page - I also tried it inside the loop near the quote class, but again it crashes the page... Do I need to include it within my main loop do you think? Ive updated with the whole loop... :)

Comment: Thank  you - really appreciate you taking the time :)

Comment: where are the functions you are using what do they do like get_title() and so on are they called results from a db?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned - It's a Wordpress Website - so this loop pulls in the posts - heres the page: http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net/insights/ if the category is clients (14) then it will display a different elements in each 'card' the inner elements of the clients cards (Quote, button, video) show up if the fields have been filled in by the user but if they are empty they don't.

Comment: try it now i left off a semi colon .

Comment: Ah perfect - thank you so much that works! just inside the main loop :) Thanks again for looking Jonny!

Comment: @BenoitNgô - I think I know what you mean - How would I work around this then? Feel free to venture a solution :)

Comment: @Jonny Fixed, I this using this line instead: $yourTag = "<a href='".get_the_permalink()."'>" ;

Answer (score 0):

If we refer to the documentation of [the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/)

> Displays the permalink for the current post.

So :

1. @jonny probably wanna say `$yourTag = "<a href=\"".the_permalink()."\">" ;`
2. @jonny's tactic can not work using this function. `$yourTag = "<a href=\"".get_the_permalink()."\">" ;`

What you can do is to store get_field result inside a variable and use [get_the_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)

```
<?php $currentQuote = get_field('quote');
echo !empty($currentQuote) ? '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">' : ""; ?>
<!----- Your content goes there ---->
<?php echo !empty($currentQuote) ? "</a>" : ""; ?>
```

I do not have wordpress so i can not test this code

Comment: you can keep @jonny response as the resolution he will probably edit when needed

Comment: Thanks! - I have currently fixed is using a concatenation operator, the dots instead of the slashes as per your number 1...  but ill play with the code above and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Surely all you're looking for is 2 different statements. 1 condition where the quote is active and 1 condition when it is not?

```
<?php if( get_field('quote') ): ?>
    <a href="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>">
        CODE AND CONTENT HERE
    </a>
<?php else; ?>
    CODE AND CONTENT HERE
<?php endif; ?>
```

The downside to the above is that you'll have to past your display code twice which is fine but not necessary.

Looking at the accepted answer, this can also do some work as there is no need to define an else, nor is there a reason to echo an empty object, when you can check to see if it's empty.

```
$permalink = "";
<?php if(get_field('quote')){
    $permalink = "<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" title="get_the_title();">" ;
}?>
```

No need for an else statement.

Then at the start of your code put:

```
<?php if(!empty($permalink)): echo $permalink; endif;?>
```

This then means 's you're not echoing an empty object since it recognises it's empty.